# Using BQ command line change configuration configuration.load.quote

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to know how using BQ command line tool I can change configuration of a BigQuery API job. E.g., I want to change configuration.load.quote property from command line tool. Is there is any way. I need this to load a table with field double quote(") inside.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot modify a job once it is created, but I guess what you want is set the quote property when creating the job.

In most cases, `bq help <command>` will get you what you need. Here's the output of `bq help load`. As you can see, you just have to specify `--quote="'"` after the command but before the arguments.

```
$ bq help load
Python script for interacting with BigQuery.


USAGE: bq.py [--global_flags] <command> [--command_flags] [args]


load     Perform a load operation of source into destination_table.

         Usage:
         load <destination_table> <source> [<schema>]

         The <destination_table> is the fully-qualified table name of table to
         create, or append to if the table already exists.

         The <source> argument can be a path to a single local file, or a
         comma-separated list of URIs.

         The <schema> argument should be either the name of a JSON file or a
         text schema. This schema should be omitted if the table already has
         one.

         In the case that the schema is provided in text form, it should be a
         comma-separated list of entries of the form name[:type], where type
         will default to string if not specified.

         In the case that <schema> is a filename, it should contain a single
         array object, each entry of which should be an object with properties
         'name', 'type', and (optionally) 'mode'. See the online documentation
         for more detail:
         https://developers.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery

         Note: the case of a single-entry schema with no type specified is
         ambiguous; one can use name:string to force interpretation as a
         text schema.

         Examples:
         bq load ds.new_tbl ./info.csv ./info_schema.json
         bq load ds.new_tbl gs://mybucket/info.csv ./info_schema.json
         bq load ds.small gs://mybucket/small.csv name:integer,value:string
         bq load ds.small gs://mybucket/small.csv field1,field2,field3

         Arguments:
         destination_table: Destination table name.
         source: Name of local file to import, or a comma-separated list of
         URI paths to data to import.
         schema: Either a text schema or JSON file, as above.

         Flags for load:

/home/David/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bq.py:
  --[no]allow_jagged_rows: Whether to allow missing trailing optional columns in
    CSV import data.
  --[no]allow_quoted_newlines: Whether to allow quoted newlines in CSV import
    data.
  -E,--encoding: <UTF-8|ISO-8859-1>: The character encoding used by the input
    file. Options include:
    ISO-8859-1 (also known as Latin-1)
    UTF-8
  -F,--field_delimiter: The character that indicates the boundary between
    columns in the input file. "\t" and "tab" are accepted names for tab.
  --[no]ignore_unknown_values: Whether to allow and ignore extra, unrecognized
    values in CSV or JSON import data.
  --max_bad_records: Maximum number of bad records allowed before the entire job
    fails.
    (default: '0')
    (an integer)
  --quote: Quote character to use to enclose records. Default is ". To indicate
    no quote character at all, use an empty string.
  --[no]replace: If true erase existing contents before loading new data.
    (default: 'false')
  --schema: Either a filename or a comma-separated list of fields in the form
    name[:type].
  --skip_leading_rows: The number of rows at the beginning of the source file to
    skip.
    (an integer)
  --source_format: <CSV|NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON|DATASTORE_BACKUP>: Format of
    source data. Options include:
    CSV
    NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
    DATASTORE_BACKUP

gflags:
  --flagfile: Insert flag definitions from the given file into the command line.
    (default: '')
  --undefok: comma-separated list of flag names that it is okay to specify on
    the command line even if the program does not define a flag with that name.
    IMPORTANT: flags in this list that have arguments MUST use the --flag=value
    format.
    (default: '')
```

Comment: I am glad to hear that. On Stack OVerflow it is customary to accept the answer, so that the person who answers gets points and people who visit the question know that the answer worked. If you can do that it's great.

Comment: Thanks David. My curent point does not allowing me to vote up for this answer. Thanks a lot by the way.